# GStreamer - local mp4 to rtpopuspay udp stream

Tags: node.js, gstreamer

I am trying to switch from test audio to an mp4 file. This is in NodeJS.

Test audio - working:

```
      const audioArgs = [
        // Generate test audio ✅
        "audiotestsrc wave=ticks",
        "audio/x-raw,rate=8000,channels=1",
        "audioconvert",
        "queue",
        "opusenc",
        "rtpopuspay",
        `udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=${audioPort}`,
      ]
```

Local mp4 - not working:

```
      const audioArgs = [
        // Audio from file ❌
        "filesrc location=noise.mp4",
        "audio/x-raw,rate=8000,channels=1",
        "audioconvert",
        "queue",
        "opusenc",
        "rtpopuspay",
        `udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=${audioPort}`,
      ]
```